# google API autocomplete not working properly

Tags: javascript

I am totally new with autocomplete google API and I have few mistakes in code but I don't see a way to fix them since I have started using JS few months ago.

If anyone can show me solution to my problem which is next, thank you.

**So the problem is next:**
When user comes to my website and starts typing his address I would like to have some default bounds that when user starts typing some address it will show him addresses only for Waterford City, Tramore or Ferrybank unless the users strats typing address that is not in either of those city's or starts with "London"

You can see my website working here :

[stjepan-cizmek.from.hr/kollect_2016_08_26/](http://stjepan-cizmek.from.hr/kollect_2016_08_26/)

with google autocomplete API

It should work as i told above and also if user puts some address that is not valid like let say Dublin it pops up a modal saying so as it is now.

Thanks everyone!

Code example:

HTML

```
<div id="locality">
<input class="form-control" style="font-size:25px;color:black;" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your home address" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['address']) ? $_SESSION['address'] : (isset($_SESSION['user']['address']) ? $_SESSION['user']['address'] : '') ;?>"
onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" name="address" required>
<input type="hidden" name="lat"id="lat" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="long" id="long" value="">
 </div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        /*function initialize() {
            var options = {
                language: 'en-GB',
                types: ['(cities)'],
                componentRestrictions: { country: "ie" }
            };
            var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input , options);
            console.log('autocomplete', autocomplete);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        */


var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
    var options = {

        language: 'en-GB',
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: { country: "ie" },
        types: ['geocode']
    };
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete')), options);
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    for (var componentPart in componentForm) {
        if (document.getElementById(componentPart)) {
            document.getElementById(componentPart).value = '';
            document.getElementById(componentPart).disabled = false;
        }
        //else {
        //  console.log('Sorry but we dont have service in that area!!');
        //  $("#myModal3").modal();

        //  $('#proceed').prop('disabled', true);
        //  return false;
        //}
    }

    $("#autocomplete").change(function () {
                $("#autocomplete").val('');
              });
  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  if (place.address_components) {
      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
          var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]]
          city = ['Waterford', 'Ferrbybank', 'Tramore']; 
              console.log(addressType, val);
          if (addressType == 'locality' && jQuery.inArray(val, city) != -1 ) {
              console.log('Grad je podrzan');


              //locality      
          } else if (addressType == 'locality') {
              $("#autocomplete").val('');
             console.log('Sorry but we dont have service in that area!!');
             $("#myModal3").modal();
          }
          document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.

    </script>



       <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDhl9cKowvI8PL6unASVZSA01Cm-yMyk5E&libraries=places&region=ie&callback=initAutocomplete" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `facebook`? Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## javascript code

```
  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete

Comment: <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter location" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>